# How to remove numbers from a list whose decimal part is greather than a parameter?

Tags: c++, list, visual-studio, methods, decimal

I need to create this function that goes through each number in a list and compares them to the parameter of the function in decimal places, and if the decimal place in the provided list is greater than whatever runs through the parameter, it is to be removed.

This is what I have so far, but I'm kinda stuck:

```
// Remove all values from mList that have a decimal place value larger than _decimal 
//      Example:   
//                  _decimal: 0.45
//
//                  mList: 498.28           // not removed, because .28 is not greater than .45
//                         39812.181        // not removed, because .181 is not greater than .45
//                         983.498          // removed, because .498 is greater than .45
//                         3981.89          // removed, because .89 is greater than .45
//                         487.2            // not removed, because .2 is not greater than .45
//
//                  With these values, the function would return 2
//
// In:  _decimal        The decimal value to check against (always less than 1.0)
//
// Return: The total number of values removed
int RemoveDecimalGreater(float _decimal) {
    
    list<float>::iterator iter = mList.begin();

    while (iter != mList.end())
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: `fmod(*iter, 1.0)` sounds like a good place to start. [Here's some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod). Watch out for the sign if you're given a negative number.

Comment: Read about std::floor and related functions.

Comment: Also keep an eye on the iterator. When you remove an element from the list, it's not valid to increment anymore. You can use the return value from `erase` or you can go in a completely different direction with [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: And of COURSE I forgot that `std::list` has its own whiz-bang built in [`remove_if `](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) that turns it almost into a one-liner.

Comment: @user4581301 just note that this function wants to return the number of elements removed, but `std::list::remove_if()` does not return the number of items removed until C++20, so you would have to count the removed elements manually in earlier versions.

Comment: @Remy The compiler I had to work with capped out at c++17. My plan would have been `pre = mList.size()`, `remove_if(blah blah blah)`, `return pre - mList.size()` and hope I wouldn't get a list that overflowed `int`

Comment: @user4581301 good point, I forgot about `size()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::modf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf) to get the decimal portion of a `float` (or `double`).

If you are using C++20 or higher, `std::list` has a `remove_if()` method that returns the number of elements removed, so you can simply return that value as-is, eg:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

int RemoveDecimalGreater(float _decimal)
{
    return static_cast<int>(
        mList.remove_if(
            [=](float num){
                float ipart;
                return (std::modf(num, &ipart) > _decimal);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Prior to C++20, `std::list::remove_if()` does not return the number of elements removed, but you can return the difference in the list's `size()` before and after removing elements, eg:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

int RemoveDecimalGreater(float _decimal)
{
    auto startSize = mList.size();
    mList.remove_if(
        [=](float num){
            float ipart;
            return (std::modf(num, &ipart) > _decimal);
        }
    );
    return static_cast<int>(startSize - mList.size());
}
```

Or, you can count the individual removals using a capturing lambda (C++11 and later) or functor (prior to C++11), eg:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

int RemoveDecimalGreater(float _decimal)
{
    int numRemoved = 0;

    mList.remove_if(
        [=, &numRemoved](float num){
            float ipart;
            if (std::modf(num, &ipart) > _decimal) {
                ++numRemoved;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );

    return numRemoved;
}
```

```cpp
#include <cmath>

struct ifGreater
{
    float decimal;
    int &count;

    ifGreater(float decimal, int &count) : decimal(decimal), count(count) {}

    bool operator()(float num) const {
        float ipart;
        if (std::modf(num, &ipart) > decimal) {
            ++count;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

int RemoveDecimalGreater(float _decimal)
{    
    int numRemoved = 0;
    mList.remove_if(ifGreater(_decimal, numRemoved));
    return numRemoved;
}
```

Otherwise, you can just loop through the `std::list` manually to remove matching elements individually using `std::list::erase()`, eg:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

int RemoveDecimalGreater(float _decimal)
{    
    std::list<float>::iterator iter = mList.begin();
    int numRemoved = 0;

    while (iter != mList.end())
    {
        float ipart;
        if (std::modf(*iter, &ipart) > _decimal) {
            iter = mList.erase(iter);
            ++numRemoved;
        }
        else {
            ++iter;
        }
    }

    return numRemoved;
}
```